# To save the json timezone in datepicker

Tags: arrays, react-native, datepicker, autocompletetextview, react-native-flatlist

I'm new to react native. I want to display the time according to country. I have one json file in which all time zones, lat,lng are present according to country. I have implemented autocomplete. [Here](https://gist.github.com/erdem/8c7d26765831d0f9a8c62f02782ae00d) is the json file of countries and timezones is.

I want that timezone in date-picker to display the current time of the country. My code is

```
render() {
const { query } = this.state;
const autotime = this.findtimezone(query);
const comp = (a, b) => a.toLowerCase().trim() === b.toLowerCase().trim();
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
  <Autocomplete
      autoCapitalize="none"
      autoCorrect={false}
      containerStyle={styles.autocompleteContainer}
      data={autotime.length === 1 && comp(query, autotime[0].name) ? [] : autotime}
      defaultValue={this.state.timeZone}
      onChangeText={text => this.setState({ query: text })}
      placeholder="Enter Location"
      renderItem={({ name, release_date }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ query: name })}>
          <Text style={styles.itemText}>
            {name} 
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
    />
    <View style={styles.descriptionContainer}>
    {autotime.length > 0 ? (
        <Text style={styles.infoText}>{this.state.query}</Text>
      ) : (
        <Text style={styles.infoText}>Enter Location</Text>
      )}
    </View>
```

Above code is for autocomplete in which i'm displaying the countries name.
In flatlist i have to display the data.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? SO is not a free code-writing-service, so you should at least share some approaches

Comment: i'm trying to implement to put the timezone in datepicker.

Comment: but i'm not able to.

Comment: @NicoHaase sure i'll provide you the code plzz check my updated question